# Can tasks be used to make a list with \itemindent = \labelwidth + \labelsep

Tags: tasks

My question will use terms from the diagram below.

Using the `tasks` environment from the `tasks` package, is it possible to make lists where `\itemindent = \labelwidth + \labelsep`? The objective is to have lines in "Item 1" beyond the first line have their left boundary line up with the left boundary of the "Label".

[All my experiments with `tasks` have only managed to make something where the "Label" is completely to the left of the entire "Item 1". In other words, I believe, where `\itemindent = 0`. ]

[image]

Comment: You mean like [this](http://i.imgur.com/QTzMfeF.png)?

Comment: @alwaysask Yes, that's right. Was that made with tasks?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not too happy with the code. I'll post it though till someone more knowledgeable than me comes with a nicer solution.

Comment: The next version (0.12) will support this natively. I'll add an answer once the new version reaches TeX Live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 0.12 when `label-width`+`label-offset`>`item-indent` the labels no longer stick into the margin but into text block of the item. This means you now only need a setup like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,microtype}

\usepackage{tasks}[2016/08/13]% v0.12 or newer

\settasks{
  label-width = 1em ,
  label-offset = .5em ,
  item-indent = 0em ,
  column-sep = 2em
}

\begin{document}

Some text:
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task \lipsum*[66]
  \task \lipsum*[75] 
\end{tasks}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding this feature. I just now was able to come back to this, upgrade my TeX distribution, update tasks, and try this out. It works great for my needs, so thank you again. 

Do you have a suggestion for how I would nicely indent the entire `tasks` environment some? If there is a way to do it with `tasks` itself, I would use that way. Otherwise I can wrap the `tasks` environment in something else to achieve that indentation. In the past I achieved this artificially by making `\labelwidth` be wide and using `label-align=right`. That hack won't work with this new feature you added.

Comment: Something like this? `\settasks{
  label-width = 3em ,
  label-offset = .5em ,
  item-indent = 2em ,
  column-sep = 0em
}`

Comment: Perfect. I didn't realize item-indent would work that way with the new feature. Thank you!